# Google Speech Recognizer - define 2 optional languages

Tags: javascript, google-api, speech-recognition

I developed a web application base on JavaScript, with Google Speech Recognizer API.
 The main language should be Hebrew, and supposed to help doctors to write medical diagnosis.
The problem is that if I say medical word in English like C.T  or Diabetes that in professional language should be say in English, it writes the English word in Hebrew.
My question is, if there is any option to define multi languages option or define languages priorities that when it detect unfamiliar word it will try the second choice????

Please help me Thank you!

This is my JavaScript Code:

```
var langs =
[['Afrikaans',       ['af-ZA']],
 ['Hebrew',          ['he-IL']],
 ['Bahasa Melayu',   ['ms-MY']],
 ['Català',          ['ca-ES']],
 ['Čeština',         ['cs-CZ']],
 ['Deutsch',         ['de-DE']],
 ['English',         ['en-AU', 'Australia'],
                     ['en-CA', 'Canada'],
                     ['en-IN', 'India'],
                     ['en-NZ', 'New Zealand'],
                     ['en-ZA', 'South Africa'],
                     ['en-GB', 'United Kingdom'],
                     ['en-US', 'United States']],
 ['Español',         ['es-AR', 'Argentina'],
                     ['es-BO', 'Bolivia'],
                     ['es-CL', 'Chile'],
                     ['es-CO', 'Colombia'],
                     ['es-CR', 'Costa Rica'],
                     ['es-EC', 'Ecuador'],
                     ['es-SV', 'El Salvador'],
                     ['es-ES', 'España'],
                     ['es-US', 'Estados Unidos'],
                     ['es-GT', 'Guatemala'],
                     ['es-HN', 'Honduras'],
                     ['es-MX', 'México'],
                     ['es-NI', 'Nicaragua'],
                     ['es-PA', 'Panamá'],
                     ['es-PY', 'Paraguay'],
                     ['es-PE', 'Perú'],
                     ['es-PR', 'Puerto Rico'],
                     ['es-DO', 'República Dominicana'],
                     ['es-UY', 'Uruguay'],
                     ['es-VE', 'Venezuela']],
 ['Euskara',         ['eu-ES']],
 ['Français',        ['fr-FR']],
 ['Galego',          ['gl-ES']],
 ['Hrvatski',        ['hr_HR']],
 ['IsiZulu',         ['zu-ZA']],
 ['Íslenska',        ['is-IS']],
 ['Italiano',        ['it-IT', 'Italia'],
                     ['it-CH', 'Svizzera']],
 ['Magyar',          ['hu-HU']],
 ['Nederlands',      ['nl-NL']],
 ['Norsk bokmål',    ['nb-NO']],
 ['Polski',          ['pl-PL']],
 ['Português',       ['pt-BR', 'Brasil'],
                     ['pt-PT', 'Portugal']],
 ['Română',          ['ro-RO']],
 ['Slovenčina',      ['sk-SK']],
 ['Suomi',           ['fi-FI']],
 ['Svenska',         ['sv-SE']],
 ['Türkçe',          ['tr-TR']],
 ['български',       ['bg-BG']],
 ['Pусский',         ['ru-RU']],
 ['Српски',          ['sr-RS']],
 ['한국어',            ['ko-KR']],
 ['中文',             ['cmn-Hans-CN', '普通话 (中国大陆)'],
                     ['cmn-Hans-HK', '普通话 (香港)'],
                     ['cmn-Hant-TW', '中文 (台灣)'],
                     ['yue-Hant-HK', '粵語 (香港)']],
 ['日本語',           ['ja-JP']],
 ['Lingua latīna',   ['la']]];
for (var i = 0; i < langs.length; i++) {
  select_language.options[i] = new Option(langs[i][0], i);
}
select_language.selectedIndex = 1;
updateCountry();
select_dialect.selectedIndex = 1;
showInfo('info_start');
function updateCountry() {
  for (var i = select_dialect.options.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    select_dialect.remove(i);
  }
  var list = langs[select_language.selectedIndex];
  for (var i = 1; i < list.length; i++) {
    select_dialect.options.add(new Option(list[i][1], list[i][0]));
  }
  select_dialect.style.visibility = list[1].length == 1 ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
}
var create_email = false;
var final_transcript = '';
var recognizing = false;
var ignore_onend;
var start_timestamp;
if (!('webkitSpeechRecognition' in window)) {

    console.log("before upgrade")
  upgrade();
} else {
  start_button.style.display = 'inline-block';
  var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
  recognition.continuous = true;
  recognition.interimResults = true;
  recognition.onstart = function() {
    recognizing = true;
    showInfo('info_speak_now');
    console.log("webkitSpeechRecognition")
    start_img.src = '/static/Mic_MicroPhone_Mute.PNG';
    start_pic=document.getElementById("start_img")
    start_pic.style.height="59px";
    start_pic.style.width="43px";
  };
  recognition.onerror = function(event) {
    if (event.error == 'no-speech') {
        console.log("event error");
      start_img.src = '/static/mic.png';
      showInfo('info_no_speech');
      ignore_onend = true;
    }
    if (event.error == 'audio-capture') {
            console.log("event caputre");
      start_img.src = '/static/mic.png';
      showInfo('info_no_microphone');
      ignore_onend = true;
    }
    if (event.error == 'not-allowed') {
            console.log("even not allowed");
      if (event.timeStamp - start_timestamp < 100) {
        showInfo('info_blocked');
      } else {
        showInfo('info_denied');
      }
      ignore_onend = true;
    }
  };
  recognition.onend = function() {
    recognizing = false;
    if (ignore_onend) {
      return;
    }
    console.log("init mic image");
    start_img.src = '/static/mic.png';
    if (!final_transcript) {
      showInfo('info_start');
      return;
    }
    showInfo('');

//    if (window.getSelection) {
//      window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
//      var range = document.createRange();
//      range.selectNode(document.getElementById('final_span'));
//      window.getSelection().addRange(range);
//    }
    if (create_email) {
      create_email = false;
      createEmail();
    }
  };
  recognition.onresult = function(event) {
    var interim_transcript = '';
    for (var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; ++i) {
      if (event.results[i].isFinal) {
      console.log("Final!!!!!!!!!!!!")
      console.log(final_span.value+event.results[i][0].transcript);
        final_transcript = final_span.value+event.results[i][0].transcript;

        final_span.value=final_transcript;
      } else {
        interim_transcript += event.results[i][0].transcript;
      }
    }


    final_transcript = capitalize(final_transcript);
      console.log("interim_transcript :");
    console.log(interim_transcript);
      console.log("final_transcript :");
    console.log(final_transcript);

//    final_span.value = linebreak(interim_transcript);
    if (final_transcript) {

    console.log("final transcript true");
//    final_span.value= linebreak(final_transcript);
    }
    if (final_transcript || interim_transcript) {
      showButtons('inline-block');
    }
  };
}
function upgrade() {
  start_button.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  showInfo('info_upgrade');
}
var two_line = /\n\n/g;
var one_line = /\n/g;
function linebreak(s) {
  return s.replace(two_line, '<p></p>').replace(one_line, '<br>');
}
var first_char = /\S/;
function capitalize(s) {
  return s.replace(first_char, function(m) { return m.toUpperCase(); });
}
function createEmail() {
  var n = final_transcript.indexOf('\n');
  if (n < 0 || n >= 80) {
    n = 40 + final_transcript.substring(40).indexOf(' ');
  }
  var subject = encodeURI(final_transcript.substring(0, n));
  var body = encodeURI(final_transcript.substring(n + 1));
  textarea_value=document.getElementById("final_span").value;

  window.location.href = 'mailto:?subject=' + "Puzzle-Soft Telemedicine - Speech Recognizer  " + '&body=' + textarea_value;
}
function copyButton() {
  if (recognizing) {
    recognizing = false;
    recognition.stop();
  }
  copy_button.style.display = 'none';
  copy_info.style.display = 'inline-block';
  showInfo('');
}
function emailButton() {
  if (recognizing) {
    create_email = true;
    recognizing = false;
    recognition.stop();
  } else {
    createEmail();
  }
  email_button.style.display = 'none';
  email_info.style.display = 'inline-block';
  showInfo('');
}
function startButton(event) {
  if (recognizing) {
    recognition.stop();
      console.log("StartButton if")
    return;
  }
  console.log("StartButton else")
  final_transcript = '';
  recognition.lang = select_dialect.value;
  recognition.start();
  ignore_onend = false;
//  final_span.innerHTML = '';
//  interim_span.innerHTML = '';
  start_img.src = '/static/mic.png';

  showInfo('info_allow');
  showButtons('none');
  start_timestamp = event.timeStamp;
}
function showInfo(s) {
  if (s) {
    for (var child = info.firstChild; child; child = child.nextSibling) {
      if (child.style) {
        child.style.display = child.id == s ? 'inline' : 'none';
      }
    }
    info.style.visibility = 'visible';
  } else {
    info.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
}
var current_style;
function showButtons(style) {
  if (style == current_style) {
    return;
  }
  current_style = style;
  copy_button.style.display = style;
  email_button.style.display = style;
  copy_info.style.display = 'none';
  email_info.style.display = 'none';
}

function ClearText() {
console.log("clear");
text_area_value=document.getElementById("final_span");
console.log(text_area_value);
console.log(text_area_value.value);
text_area_value.value='';
}
//var givevalue = function (my_key) {
//    return dict[my_key];
//
//    }
//
//js_json={'אדרנלypr': 'Olanzapine Teva', 'זיפאדהרה': 'Zypadhera', 'אומפראזול': 'Omeprazole', 'אומפרדקס': 'Omepradex', 'לוסק': 'Losec', 'אומפריקס': 'Omeprix', 'אומפרדקס Z': 'Omepradex Z', 'אומפרה': 'Omepra', 'אונדאנסטרון': 'Ondansetron', 'זופרן': 'Zofran', 'אודנטרון': 'Odnatron', 'אונדאנסטרון - פרזניוס': 'Ondansetron - Fresenius', 'אונדנסטרון אינובמד': 'Ondansetron Inovamed'}
//function replaceTextAreaDict() {
//textarea_result=document.getElementById("final_span");
//    textarea_words=textarea_result.split(' ') ;
//    for (var i = 0; i < textarea_result.length; i++) {
//
//    }
//
//
//
//    givevalue()
//
//}
//
//replaceTextAreaDict();
```

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot mix language.**

Speech Recognition roughly contains 3 part -> Accoustic model, Language model, and dictionary.

**Accoustic model** is the result of data training contains relationship between audio signal and phonetic

**Dictionary** contains words and how they pronounced, for e.g, word TOP are pronounced "T AH P" on the general speech recognition dictionary.

**Language model** is the connection between words to create sentences, for e.g. the word "I" is connected with "am", so the speech recognizer will very rarely (or never) give the result of "I are" or "I is".

Every Language have their own Accoustic Model (phonetic), Dictionary (words), and Language Model (sentences), so we can just mix them up.

The Question is : Is it still possible?

The Answer is : YES!

You can build your own language (in this case Medical language) using many tools, one I already tried called CMU Sphinx / Pocket Sphinx. You can build your own model, train it, and make a dictionary out of it. It will be alot work to do, but you can configure anything you will need for speech recognition.

Link for any platform implementation : https://github.com/cmusphinx